# Unity ios drag with easing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Using the Touch inputs I know how to drag a gameobject. But what I need to do is to (upon release of drag) check the speed of the drag and have the object move a bit further. So if I drag the object fast and release it it will move a bit in the dragged direction after releasing it. As it is now it simply stops at the position where I remove my finger. Anyone know how this is done?

What I have now is:

```
        private Vector3 dist, distEnd;
        float posX;
        float posY;

    void OnMouseDown() {

            dist = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint (transform.position);
            posX = Input.mousePosition.x - dist.x;
            posY = Input.mousePosition.y - dist.y;


        }

        void OnMouseDrag()
        {
            Vector3 curPos = new Vector3 (Input.mousePosition.x - posX, Input.mousePosition.y - posY, dist.z);
            Vector3 worldPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (curPos);
            transform.position = worldPos;

        }

        void OnMouseUp() {
            distEnd = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint (transform.position);


        }
```

Then I added a RigidBody2d to the object - trying to add force to it - but I suppose I need to calculate the speed and direction of drag/mouse - before I can add directional force to the object??

```
    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().AddForce (Vector2 (FORCE_DIRECTION_X, FORCE_DIRECTION_Y));
```

But I'm having difficulties calculating direction and speed of drag.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Sure we know, but can you give as sample of your code to make a base for answer?

Comment: Sorry - here the code I have so far.

Answer (score 0):

Right, I finally found an answer :-) I have included a script for others to use (I did not come up with the solution though).

Maybe someone could use it as well - alter variable "SmoothTime" so set time before drag-speed is 0.

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;

 public class dragMap : MonoBehaviour {


private Vector3 _screenPoint;
private Vector3 _offset;
private Vector3 _curScreenPoint;
private Vector3 _curPosition;
private Vector3 _velocity;
private bool _underInertia;
private float _time = 0.0f;
public float SmoothTime = 2;
void Update()
{
    if(_underInertia && _time <= SmoothTime)
    {
        transform.position += _velocity;
        _velocity = Vector3.Lerp(_velocity, Vector3.zero, _time);
        _time += Time.smoothDeltaTime;
    }
    else
    {
        _underInertia = false;
        _time = 0.0f;
    }
}
void OnMouseDown()
{
    _screenPoint = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(gameObject.transform.position);
    _offset = gameObject.transform.position - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, _screenPoint.z));
    //Screen.showCursor = false;
    _underInertia = false;
}
void OnMouseDrag()
{
    Vector3 _prevPosition = _curPosition;
    _curScreenPoint = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, _screenPoint.z);
    _curPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(_curScreenPoint) + _offset;
    _velocity = _curPosition - _prevPosition;
    transform.position = _curPosition;
}
void OnMouseUp()
{
    _underInertia = true;
    //Screen.showCursor = true;
}
```

}